# JPA - apply @Column(columnDefinition = "Boolean") to all Basic Attributes of type Boolean

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, ddl, jpa-2.1

is it possible to set the DDL type Boolean to all @Basic attributes of type java.lang.Boolean?

I'm using Hibernate, which by default creates an sql bit as DDL type.

### Update

I currently solved it Hibernate specific by using a custom `org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect` with:

```
registerColumnType(Types.BOOLEAN, "boolean");
```

Comment: Because I asked for a generic JPA solution, but just found a specific Hibernate one, I'm reluctant to do so.

Comment: I don't think there's any JPA spec for column type generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently solved it with a **Hibernate specific way** by using a custom `org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect`:

```
public class MySqlDialect extends MySQL57InnoDBDialect {
    public MySqlDialect() {
        registerColumnType(Types.BOOLEAN, "boolean");
    }
}
```

I registered it with the Spring Boot property:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=my.MySqlDialect
```